# Does the sobel mask from fspecial find horizontal or vertical edges?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, edge-detection

So I did something like this in Matlab:

```
s = fspecial('sobel');
imshow(conv2(image, s));
```

In matlab when I create a sobel mask with `fspecial` and use that mask with `conv2` on an image, are the edges in the convoluted image the *horizontal or vertical* edges or has it already added both the horizontal and vertical edges? And what about the diagonal edges?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation to [`fspecial`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fspecial.html) tells us

> h = fspecial('sobel') returns a 3-by-3 filter h (shown below) that emphasizes horizontal edges using the smoothing effect by approximating a vertical gradient. If you need to emphasize vertical edges, transpose the filter

To transpose the filter, use

```
hvert = ( fspecial('sobel') )'
```

The [Sobel filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) is basically a smoothed derivative operator. By detecting both horizontal and vertical edges, you essentially retrieve a Sobel approximation to the gradient of the image, which also gives you diagonal edges.

To actually emphasize edges without worrying about their direction, use the magnitude of this gradient:

```
hy = fspecial('sobel');
hx = hy';
gx = imfilter(image, hx); % x component of Sobel gradient
gy = imfilter(image, hy); % y component 

gmag = hypot(gx,gy); % magnitude of Sobel gradient
```